# Dynamic part for separate Router

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

Let's say I have some routes like this:

```
GET /home/:id/foo  controllers.HomeController.foo(id: Int)
GET /home/:id/bar  controllers.HomeController.bar(id: Int)
GET /home/:id/baz  controllers.HomeController.baz(id: Int)
```

and I decided it would be nice to have them in separate files. If I split it up as I did with other routes that don't have a dynamic part, the routes are not recognized anymore even though the route lookup looks correct:

```
Action Not Found

For request 'GET /home/1/foo' 
These routes have been tried, in this order: 
1 GET/home/$id<[^/]+>/foo  controllers.HomeController.foo(id:Int)
2 GET/foo/$id<[^/]+>       controllers.HomeController.foo(id:Int)
```

routes

```
-> /home/:id  home.Routes
GET /foo/:id   controllers.HomeController.foo(id: Int)
```

home.routes

```
GET /foo  controllers.HomeController.foo(id: Int)
GET /bar  controllers.HomeController.bar(id: Int)
GET /baz  controllers.HomeController.baz(id: Int))
```

Is there a way to make this work, or is it just not possible?

Comment: I don't think you can have `/home/:id` in one file and `/foo` in another. Have you tried moving the `/:id` part to home.routes?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley yes, that works. But that's exactly what I tried to avoid. It seems you cannot hava dynamic parts in the `->`-part of the route.